# A choice list based on database values in sonata

Tags: entity, admin, sonata

is it possible to add a choice list in configureformfields with choices values mapped from the database instead of configuring it manually like this :

```
->add('testfield', 'choice', array('choices' => array(
                    '1' => 'choice 1',
                    '2' => 'choice 2',)))
```

Answer (score 0):

if the entity is correctly mapped then you can just use:

```
->add('testfield')
```

and Sonata admin will do the job.

Let's say you have a Product class linked to a Category class:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Product
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 * 
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="products")
     */
    protected $category; 

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set category
     *
     * @param Category $category
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setCategory(Category $category = null)
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get category
     *
     * @return Category
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }
}
```

Simply using:

```
->add('category')
```

will provide a select form field with all the categories.

You can also use SONATA_TYPE_MODEL if you want something more advanced:

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Admin/ProductAdmin.php

class ProductAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $imageFieldOptions = array(); // see available options below

        $formMapper
            ->add('category', 'sonata_type_model', $imageFieldOptions)
        ;
    }
}
```

The documentation is on this page: [Form Types](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/3-x/doc/reference/form_types.html#sonata-type-model)

Hope this helps!